# What is the root URL of an ec2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to give the root URL for my ec2 server, can someone please give me the syntax of the root URL of a general ec2 server? (Just so I know what syntax to give my specific web server details in). I tried this one:

```
http://ec2-**-**-**-**.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

but it doesn't work, flash builder says that it is invalid, but it works in a browser so I can't see how it can be.

Comment: what do you mean by a `root url` ?

Comment: I am building an application in adobe flash builder, trying to connect it to my ec2 server for databases and stuff... In the configuration, it asks for a root URL

Comment: not sure how you are connecting, but `ec2-**-**-**-**.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` is what you need (I guess ?) in order to connect.

Comment: Also, be sure that your EC2 instance runs from a Security Group that ALLOW TCP 80 ingress traffic

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, assuming what you mean is what is the general syntax for an EC2 server DNS name?

It's

```
ec2-<external-ip-with-dashes-instead-of-dots>.<region>.compute.amazonaws.com
```

so yes:

```
ec2-**-**-**-**.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

is correct for the `eu-west-1` region.

Now it looks like you have another problem, either you are not allowing port 80 on your security group associated with the instance or you are just not running anything on port 80. i.e. apache, nginx, etc.